# What is the quickest way to convert a large XML file into a SQLite file?

Tags: iphone, xml, sqlite

I am retrieving data from an XML file but the file contains more than 15000 records, so my application is getting slowed. So I want to convert it into **SQLLite** file (by using programmatically or by using any tool).

Please provide me any solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Core Data. Parse the date, create managed objects and let Core Data persist those objects to a sqlite database.

The the following benefit will be, that you don't have to care for sql statements later on.

To prepopulate the core data db read [this article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data). I'd write a simple xml2sqlite importer like in Ruby or PHP.

If you are not a friend of scripting languages then have a look at [SQLite Manager](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/) it's a Firefox Plugin to manage SQLite database and it's capable of importing XML.

Comment: hi nick weaver .i takes more time to parse the XML file.so i want to convert the XML file into sqlite file.can u please give me any suggestion on this question.

Comment: Where does the xml come from? From a server or does it come shipped with the bundle?

Comment: Updated the answer. If you ask, why Core Data anyway? I'd say, it's easy to use and blends in the iPhone environment very nicely.

Comment: If you are new to iPhone development it'll be some steps but it's worth the effort.

Comment: hi nick can u please tell how to use SQlite manager and how to import XML please.i just tried for it but i can't.

Comment: I'll try to help later today.